# Ui flickering when reading value from database using room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

My code is supposed to use room to get flashcards filtered by topic and then display it. The flashcard does get displayed but the text keeps on flickering. Any help would be appreciated.

ViewModel

```
class FlashcardViewModel(private val flashcardsRepository: FlashcardsRepository): ViewModel() {
    
    val timeoutMillis = 5_000L

    fun getFlashcardsFilteredByTopic(topic: String): StateFlow<List<Flashcard>> {
        val flashcardUiState: StateFlow<List<Flashcard>> = flashcardsRepository.getFlashcardsStreamFilteredByTopic(topic = topic)
            .stateIn(
                scope = viewModelScope,
                started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(timeoutMillis),
                initialValue = listOf(Flashcard())
            )
        return flashcardUiState
    }
}
```

Composable functions to display the flashcard

```
@Composable
fun FlashcardScreen(
    topic: String
) {
    val viewModel: FlashcardViewModel = viewModel(factory = Factory)

    val flashcardUiState by viewModel.getFlashcardsFilteredByTopic(topic).collectAsState()

    var currentIndex by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf(0) }
    val currentFlashcard = flashcardUiState[currentIndex]

    Flashcard(flashcard = currentFlashcard)
    
}

@Composable
fun Flashcard(flashcard: Flashcard) {

        Text(
            text = flashcard.question
        )

        Text(
            text = flashcard.answer,
        )

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `getFlashcardsFilteredByTopic` in each recomposition. This function creates new `StateFlow` with default value of empty card (`listOf(Flashcard())`) and presumably executes the database query and updates the flow with the result, which triggers the recomposition and it all starts again.

One possible solution would be to put the `topic` in the ViewModel and do something like this:

```
// FlashcardViewModel
val topic = MutableStateFlow("")
val flashCards = topic.flatMapLatest { topic ->
    flashcardsRepository.getFlashcardsStreamFilteredByTopic(topic = topic)
}.stateIn(...)
```

Or you can `remember` the flow you create in ViewModel, this will only call `getFlashcardsFilteredByTopic` when the topic changes:

```
// FlashcardScreen
val flashCardsFlow = remember(topic) {
    viewModel.getFlashcardsFilteredByTopic(topic)
}
val flashcardUiState by flashCardsFlow.collectAsState()
```